# Gluon Mobile - ResourceBundle.getBundle and class.getResource don't load the resources

Tags: gluon-mobile

I'm currently porting a javafx desktop app to be a gluon mobile app. I'm a completely beginner using this platform.

When launched as a desktop app, it works properly.

When launched on the ipad simulator the application breaks with messages like the ones below.

```
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.objectdb.ui.language.Locale_en_EN'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.objectdb.ui.language.Locale_en_EN</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'com.objectdb.ui.language.Locale_en'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>com.objectdb.ui.language.Locale_en</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.xml.stream.FactoryFinder$ClassLoaderFinderConcrete</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
[WARN] java.lang.Class: Class.forName() failed to load 'javax.servlet.Servlet'. Use the -forcelinkclasses command line option or add <forceLinkClasses><pattern>javax.servlet.Servlet</pattern></forceLinkClasses> to your robovm.xml file to link it in.
```

I can't find where to include these on the gluon mobile app, if somebody could point me on the right direction, documentation, etc...

Comment: See the build gradle file. If you are using the Gluon plugin you will find under the iOS configuration the `forceLinkClasses` list that lets you add packages names from your project and dependencies.

Comment: Thx! That worked!